# Database Collation issue in Sitecore Commerce Server 8.2.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-commerce-server

I have installed Sitecore Commerce Server 8.2.1 and now experience the below error when loading my Sitecore site:

[image: sitecore]

When I checked the Commerce Server Manager I noticed that the connection string of one of the partitions is incorrect, but when I try to save it I get the following error message:

[image: error]

Can someone help me to solve this issue, please?

*I didn't change the collation type of the database